# GTK application hangs when created a child process

Tags: c, gtk

I am creating a GTK application in C. I am creating a child process using fork and then replacing it with execve("crawler",arg,env); which crawls my home directory and stores all the filenames in a file. 
Now, this child process takes some time (about 2-5 minutes). 
In the mean time, when this child process is running, the main GTK parent program is waiting. 
But when the child process is running, after some time, the GTK application hangs.

I have tried gdk_thread_enter()/leave() in my main function.
But still I am the application is hanging.

Please, point out a mistake if any or else suggest any modification.

Answer (score 1):

execve does not create a child process, it replaces the current process with the child. Are you sure you used fork() first, and then execve() from within the child?

**EDIT** since you're already using fork/execve, perhaps the child process is still interacting with Gtk somehow. Best to use Glib/Gtk+-specific functions for invoking the crawler -- try, for instance, [g_spawn_command_line_async](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-command-line-async)

Comment: Yes, I have used fork() and then created a child process and then replaced it using execve(). Sorry, for not explaining it properly. Edited the question to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean by *"when this child process is running, the main GTK parent program is waiting"* is that your code executes a wait(), waitid(), waitpid() in its main thread, then the app will indeed suspend execution until a child terminates (unless you've selected NOHANG option).

If your Gtk app doesn't need to coordinate further with your crawler program, just use the previously-mentioned 
[g_spawn_command_line_async](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-command-line-async) routine, and do not set G_SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD.  If you do need to coordinate, you could set that flag, and create a [GChildWatch source](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-child-watch-source-new), or perhaps could use one of the g_spawn pipe routines.

As I interpret [gdk_thread_enter()/leave()](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gdk/gdk-Threads.html), they are locking or unlocking threading, rather than running or stopping new threads.  Gtk callbacks run in the main thread, so as indicated above, a blocking waitpid() in a callback will hang the Gtk app.  A non-blocking waitpid() in a timer callback (eg) is not a problem, however.

Comment: By hangs I had meant, it freezes(goes black). Anyways, I will try g_spawn_command_line_async and let you know whether it solves the prob.